# Unity use UI panel in multiple different contexts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a panel that has 3 subpanel: Equipment, Inventory, Item Description.

Now I created the new panel that will have 2 subpanel: Shop, Inventory. Is there a way to use the same Inventory sub panel in both of the main panels?

I could just duplicate every action that happens with inventory to both of the panels. But it seems wrong. I think there should be a way to use the same panel in both of the situations(In store and out of the store);

The inventory panel is using the EventSystem, that allows easily to create Drag n Drop items in inventory. So duplicating it for both of the views creates a difficult scenario where when I drag the item out of the inventory of one panel it also needs to disappear in the other panel. So it needs some synchronization events or something.

I created the event using this https://youtu.be/c47QYgsJrWc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bring out the panels you need to reuse(like Inventory panel) from their parent panels and put them inside another panel naming like **ReusablePanel**.
And activate or deactivate the **ReusablePanel** when needed.

Comment: But if the position is different. In first case inventory is in middle, second case inventory is on the right.

Comment: You can save the multiple positions of the panel in multiple variables. Then set the position of the inventory panel accordingly.